# Default keyboard is not coming when Barcode Scanner Device is Connected by Bluetooth in Ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, bluetooth, barcode-scanner

When I connect bluetooth barcode scanner with my iPad. Default keyboard not show.

So, How can i work with both keyboard(barcode scanner + default keyboard) in my application.

Comment: @Enrico Default keyboard not show in any application in iPad. but in my application works on both things. let me help, if you have any idea about this things...